# Approximate 4 circles inside ellipse to get the radii

Tags: python, opencv

I need the approximate radii of the following ellipse.
[image: Ellipse I'm working on]

The bottom/top and left/right radii should be the same nevertheless need to be checked. Which means 4 radii should be the result of my code. I did the following in paint, the green circle should give me the top radius and red the left (the right and bottom one aren't drawn here). [image: Visualising my idee with paint]

The idea I'm working on is to crop the image (left/right/top/bottom side) and approximate circles to the cropped images. With the cv2.findContours-feature some white pixels get recognized as highlighted here.[image: cropped left side]

Is there a way to approximate my drawn red circle from above with these given coordinates? The problems I've seen on the internet are all with a given center point or angle which I don't have. Is there a cv2 function that draws circles with only some given coordinates or something similar?

Comment: Use this function :  cv2.fitEllipse(points)   and pass contour points

Comment: Checkout the code here :https://github.com/AlliedToasters/circle-fit  . It's actually easy to write your own fitting algorithm using  NumPy ... The problem with the Minimum enclosing circle is that it doesn't work if you have outlier points that are far away from the actual edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function : cv2.fitEllipse(points) and pass contour points -Ziri

Yes this did the trick. I got the radii after your function with:

`(x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(i)`